# Qt, OpenCV, Windows or Linux, package management?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, qt, opencv, package

I made this tutorial about a year and a half ago:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akAAAvGyLn0

To summarize, at the time, the best way I could find to get Qt and OpenCV running together on Windows 10 was to download the source for OpenCV, download CMake, check the Qt option, compile OpenCV fully from source, and then edit the .pro file within Qt Designer.

This process is very time consuming (the video linked above is about an hour) and results in a configuration where OpenCV has to be in the exact location specified in the .pro file settings, which are cryptic and very non-intuitive.

With package management having progressed quite a bit in the last year and a half, I'd like to re-do this video using some sort of package management to use pre-compiled binaries and greatly ease and expedite the process.

Within Visual Studio I use NuGet packages for almost everything as they are quick and work great.  Moreover, making your own NuGet if there is not an existing one is not that difficult.

So for those familiar with Qt and/or package management (outside of Visual Studio) more than I am, here are my questions:

-Does Qt have a NuGet equivalent?  I just downloaded / installed the most recent Qt (5.8) and I can't seem to find any NuGet equivalent in the installer or the menus (this seems very archaic for 2017)

-If there is not a NuGet equivalent within Qt, is there an industry standard package manager that would work with Qt and Windows?  What about for common Linux distributions such as Ubuntu?  I found this link: http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/11/using-opencv-3-qt-creator-3-2-qt-5-3/ is this the best way to use Qt / OpenCV on Linux ?

-It seems Chocolatey has an OpenCV package: https://chocolatey.org/packages/OpenCV but since the default compile options for OpenCV don't include Qt, and this page seems to state that the package is compiled with the default options, I gather Qt is not supported, is this correct?  Even if Qt is supported, will putting the Chocolatey OpenCV package name in the .pro file be recognized by Qt, or is that only a Linux thing?

I would really like to continue supporting Qt in my OpenCV tutorials, but with how quick and painless it is to use OpenCV within Visual Studio now (just choose an applicable NuGet package) and how difficult it is in Qt, I'm considering no longer using Qt until they get a NuGet package equivalent going.  Can anybody provide assistance with the above questions / concerns?

Comment: This appears to be some self promoting video, so SPAM.

Comment: And why is this question tagged `linux`? It only talks about MS-Windows.

Comment: This is not a self-promoting post at all, I happened to mention part of the context of use.  Many people over the years have used my videos and found them quite helpful, I don't see any harm in giving back to the community.  I make very little money from my videos, I make them out of interest of the subject matter and sharing knowledge with others.  As far as applicability to Linux, if you press Ctrl+F on your keyboard and type "Linux" you will clearly see I mentioned Qt / OpenCV configuration on Linux 3 times in my post so the Linux tag is clearly applicable.

Comment: Qt and openCV are both readily available in the repositories all major Linux distributions offer. So the installation is somewhere about three clicks.

Comment: These are Windows and Visual Studio problems. As people said earlier, on Linux you have a package manager that has all necessary packages.